# Replacing new lines with "\n" and have it be unit testable?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a block of code which looks like this :

```
 String myJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object).replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "\\\\n") + "\n";
```

Now, that code lives inside a "callable" block - and as such, is useless when it comes to unit testing.

I know I could do something along the lines of pulling the regex into a Pattern class... and then matching against it that way - but I wanted to get some input regarding the best practice here - I don't have as much unit testing under my belt as I would like to have, and I know there are always better ways to do these things.

The actual block of code, for better reference

```
    Callable<Boolean> doStuff = new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object).replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "\\\\n") + "\n";
            // TODO : Add functionality which adds this string to a list.
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you share some more context? The "unit" that's unit tested is usually an entire method. Is this a method on its own? Is it part of some larger functionality?

Comment: Hey @Mureinik, I added the code above into the question - I don't need help with the TODO part, where I will be adding it to the list, I just need to know how I might be able to unit test the replace code, with the regex etc in it... how I might break that out into a class and be able to test that, for example.

Comment: Consider using `\\R`, introduced with Java 8 and meaning "any new line sequence in any OS" as your regex.

Comment: Thanks, @Bohemian, I will take that into consideration, but for now I need to work out the unit testing aspect of this.

Comment: Either extract it or check that you have the correct value in your `list` based on `object`.

Comment: Why do you care what the newline is? Java doesn't.

Comment: I don't think anyone here really understands my question - I am not trying to test the list, I am trying to test the regex alone. The functionality might change, the way we store this might change, the regex is what we plan on keeping.

Comment: @EJP because this data gets sent out to other applications, and those applications are not necessarily written in java.

Answer (score 1):

Break out the code into a (unit testable) method:

```
Callable<Boolean> doStuff = new Callable<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        String json = escapeNewlines(mapper.writeValueAsString(object)) + "\n";
        // TODO : Add functionality which adds this string to a list.
        return true;
    }
};

// Unit test this utility method
public static String escapeNewlines(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\R+", "\\\\n"); // Note use of \R
}
```

Comment: I think he actually want's the unit test code. Something like a method that call his method with some predicates/assertions to check if the regex will break or not, although I may be wrong... It is not much clear...